# Using `sed` in Android without `g` modifier?

Tags: sed, busybox

I have Stericson busy box installed in my rooted Nexus 10.

I wanted to replace the first instance of `</verse-sub-section>` with `</section>` in the file here:

```
          <section>Psalm of David</verse-sub-section>
          <verse-sub-section>David Weeps</verse-sub-section>
```

`sed -i 's#</verse-sub-section>#</section>#' file` replaces all `</verse-sub-section>` with `</section>` even when I do not use the `g` modifier at the end.

Is this due to busybox? Or is my command wrong? What should I use to achieve this (in anroid with busybox)?

Busybox version:1.23.1

Comment: no, sed would works on line by line. Chnege your sed command to, `sed -i '0,s#</verse-sub-section>#</section>#' file`

Answer (score 1):

In order to limit the replacement to a portion of the file up to and including the first matching instance, you can prepend the substitute command with a *range* of the form `1,\#pattern#` i.e.

```
busybox sed '1,\#</verse-sub-section># s#</verse-sub-section>#</section>#' file
```

Note the use of the backslash escape before the alternate delimiter `\#` except where it is introduced by the `s` command.

Note that this will not have the desired behaviour if a match occurs in the first line; GNU sed supports a range of the form `0,\#pattern#` to handle this situation, but busybox sed - at least the version I am able to test, `BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-8ubuntu1)` - does not appear to.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous.  If you want to find the ***very first*** instance
of `</verse-sub-section>` *in the entire file*, and replace it with `</section>`,
then see the other answer(s).  My interpretation is that, given the input

```
1    <section>Genesis</verse-sub-section>
2    <verse-sub-section>In the beginning, God ...</verse-sub-section>
3    <section>Psalm of David</verse-sub-section>
4    <verse-sub-section>David Weeps</verse-sub-section>
```

you want to replace `</verse-sub-section>` with `</section>` on lines 1 and 3. 
If that's your question, the answer is

```
sed -i 's#\(<section>.*\)</verse-sub-section>#\1</section>#' file
```

Putting `<section>` in the *old* field of the `s/old/new/` command guarantees that only lines containing `<section>` will be processed. 
The `\(…\)` delimits a part of the line: the part starting with `<section>`
and going up to (but not including) the `</verse-sub-section>`. 
And the `\1` in the *new* field causes the identified substring of the matched string
to be inserted back into the file -- i.e., left untouched.

At least that's how it works in normal versions of *nix. 
Android shouldn't be any different, but I can't guarantee that it will work in busybox.